# google drive api access token expires in ~12h even when i use refresh token

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

i'm using php library google-api-php-client-2.2.0

i'm trying to automate update of a google drive spreadsheet with values each hour by executing php script via crontab

here is how i get my client to work with google drive service

```
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        }
    }

    return $client;
}
```

and below is a code which searches for the correct google drive file and updates it once found

```
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Drive API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', __DIR__ . '/drive-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE)));

$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

$data = get_results_as_string($all); // this is data to be updated with

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
}else{
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
        if ($file->getName() == $GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_NAME){
            $fileId = $file->getId();
            $emptyFile = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
            $service->files->update($fileId, $emptyFile, array(
                'data' => $data,
                'mimeType' => 'text/csv',
                'uploadType' => 'media',
                'fields' => 'id')
            );
        }
    }
}
```

i expect that when access token i grab from CLIENT_SECRET_PATH file expires - i will fetch (since i have appropriate check for this) new access token from refresh token i have in the same file.
i overwrite the file with what has been fetched and go further with updates and routine.

however this works for around of ~12 hours (i'm running this once per hour) and then stops to be working.
appreciate if you could help on this please

Comment: Define stops working what is your error message exactly.   Any reason you have chosen not to use a service account?  Wouldn't it be easier to just use the sheets api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured this out, below lines are to look up thru the files:

```
$optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
```

default *pageSize* value which is 10 is way too little. after some time doc ID you're looking for won't be returned within first 10 results. variable is configurable within range [1;1000]
i put 1000 and it has solved the issue for me.